# Does Legendary Resistance affect Power Word Kill or not, since it has no saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, saving-throw

In a battle with any Monster with the feature "Legendary Resistance" (ex. Ancient Blue Dragon), with which the monster can choose to automatically save a failed saving throw, how does this then work when a spell is  cast with no saving throw (ex. Power Word Kill)? Does the Legendary Resistance automatically render the spell null and void then? Or does the spell win out because there is no saving throw? Or is it simply a matter of DM discretion and can go either way?

Answer (score 25):

If the creature with Legendary Resistance has less than 100hp, it would kill them.

Power Word Kill has no saving throw, so Legendary Resistance does not apply.

However, a creature with Legendary Resistance very likely has more than 100HP. If it does have less, it would be a phenomenal finishing move on them (at the cost of your 9th level spell slot.)

Comment: A legendary creature would also likely make sure that when you finally faced it you would not have all your resources, to include such a spell that could possibly best it at the "final" battle.

Comment: @Slagmoth The legendary creature does not get to dictate how you expend your resources.  ;-)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast then he was played incorrectly :P. No self-respecting Legendary "Villain" would allow itself to be at a disadvantage and thus have its minions soften them up for them.

Comment: @Slagmoth I understand your point, but resources management and "keeping your reserve until you need it" are within the players remit.  I realize that not everyone plays wargames, but having a reserve for that critical moment in the battle for a counter attack, finishing strike, or last blow, is War Gaming/Tactical Technique 101. (It's also good military practice, see about 6000 years of history ...)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Agreed, however, the DM is in control of when that critical moment occurs, not the players, technically the players will have no idea when the "correct" moment to use their resources is.

Comment: @Slagmoth but it is still up to the players how and when to use those resources. That being said, this discussion is better left to chat than comments in my answer :)